# How to get DLL project to update every build in C++ project in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015

Basically, I have two projects, one which compiles to a dll and the other which consumes that dll. Right now I have a pre-build script which copies the dll into the dependent projects binary folder for use:

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)\DLLProj\Binaries\$(PlatformName)_$(Configuration)\DLLProj.dll" "$(SolutionDir)\DependentProj\Binaries\$(PlatformName)_$(Configuration)\"
```

This script seems to copy the dll upon first build but then on subsequent build and runs it is not being updated. I have to clean the build or rebuild for a new dll to get updated in my dependent projects folder. Is there a way to have my dll be rebuilt every time I just do the build and run option? Instead of having manually cleaning the build and rebuilding?

Answer (score 1):

Make the dll project part of the solution for the dependent program, then add the dll project as a dependency for the program (under build dependencies-> project dependencies

Comment: I've already done that unfortunately. Still not rebuilding the dll